# texel / pixel matching in OpenGL 3.x / 4x

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math

From what I've read in terms pixel center convention, OpenGL considers a pixel's center at its **half-pixel location**. That makes pixel centers for rasterization **"match"** texel centers for texturing.

So, if the following 4 conditions hold true:

1. the **"world"** coordinate system "exactly" matches the **viewport** resolution (ex. both 1920x1080)
2. projection is **orthographic** (glm::ortho )
3. every **texture's width/height** matches 1 to 1 (texel to pixel) those defined by its corresponding quaternion's vertices
4. **UV [0,1]** used for texture mapping

then:

- the matching between a texture's texels and viewport's pixels will be **1-to-1** ?
- no need to add/subtract any correction (+/-**0.5**) ?
- any idea on how to check that it's a 1-to-1 match ?

any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use partial derivative functions in glsl.
Partial difference derivative functions.These are fragment shader instructions wich can be used to compute the rate of variation of any value with respect to the screen-space coordinates.
This any value can be texture co ordinates
So

vec2  dx_vtc        = dFdx(texture_coordinate);
vec2  dy_vtc        = dFdy(texture_coordinate);

float len1 = length(dx_vtc);
float len2 = length(dy_vtc);

If difference in length is zero then we can conclude there is one to one mapping.

Comment: **@Paritosh Kulkarni**, pretty insightful !!! in your example you are using **2 textures** (texture coordinates), so any hints on how to do it when you have a texture (**texture coords.**) and viewport's vertices (**vertex coords.**) ? or is it the same concept but this time applied to **vertex coordinates** and **vertex coordinates** ?

Comment: I think you dnt need viewport vertices as you are considering two things here texture co ordinates and screen space position which will be available.in fragment shader stage as result of model view projection then NDC conversion and viewport transform applied to vertex position . So in fragment shader with derivative function you are considering rate of change of texture coordinates with respect to screen space co ordinates and if this is 0 we are saying they are not changing with respect to one another. I hope its clear.

Comment: Also I am not using two textures I am using derivative in x direction on texture co ordinates of same texture and  y derivative on texture coordinates of same texture.

Comment: **@Paritosh Kulkarni**, pretty clear !!! any place/documentation where I can find an example with a similar case of use ?

Comment: **@Paritosh Kulkarni**  got it ! thanks for your clarification.

Comment: http://www.aclockworkberry.com/shader-derivative-functions/    This one is nice introduction on how we can calculate mip map level to select in shader.